# Stage untracked files for commit without staging tracked file changes

Tags: git, command-line, msysgit, version-control

Oftentimes, when using git, I find myself in this situation:

- I have changes to several files, but I only want to commit parts of them.
- I have added several untracked files, which I want to track and commit.

Solving the first part is easy; I run:

```
git add -p
```

Then, I choose which hunks to stage, and which hunks remain in my working tree, but unstaged. However, git's patch mode skips over untracked files.

What I would *like* to do is something like:

```
git add --untracked
```

But no such option appears to exist.

If I have, say, six untracked files, I *could* stage them using `add` in interactive mode and the `add untracked` option, like so:

```
git add -i
a<CR>
1<CR>
2<CR>
3<CR>
4<CR>
5<CR>
6<CR>
<CR>
q<CR>
```

I feel like there is, or should be, a quicker way of doing this, though. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a git add option that does what you describe, but you can reduce the number of keystrokes required in interactive mode by using `*` instead of individual entry numbers when selecting which untracked files to add.

Comment: Good enough for what I'm doing. :)